# how I can put a link in this way style on description youtube video?

Tags: hyperlink, youtube

[image]

This link style is put with a specific mobile device or with a pay tool? I appreciate you help!

I test put the link via android device and the way mode standard link from youtube studio, but it's no same result.

Comment: What link have you tried to add to your description? From a computer on https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/edit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID, https://youtu.be/VIDEO_ID?t=2 and https://youtu.be/VIDEO_ID worked fine on a computer.

Comment: I would like that appear the youtube logo together link as like show on picture. without use emoji to do this. some channels are using this way.

Comment: I appreciate you help Sir. very much thank you. You answer is right! Thank you so much!

Comment: Then please consider accepting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75716856).

Comment: @BenjaminLoison please verify your link.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Thanks for notifying me however my answer was just deleted by a moderator 32 minutes ago for unknown reason. As far as I know they don't like answers that are kind of only made of URLs but there isn't much to said, anyway I'll consider my comment as an answer... [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

This work fine for me:

```
youtu.be/VIDEO_ID
```

The answer was @BenjaminLoison